# Are order continuous Banach lattices with weak unit weakly sequentially complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-lattices

Let $E$ be an order continuous Banach lattice with a weak unit represented as $L^\infty(\mu) \subseteq E\subseteq L^1(\mu)$. Is it true that $E$ is also a weakly sequentially complete Banach lattice?